# Send an email when attachment is deleted

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to send an email with file attached when an attachment is deleted from Opp object. How to modify this trigger to achieve this? iam getting an exception while deleting file

```
Trigger DeleteAttachment on Attachment (after delete) {
 set<Id> aId = new set<id>();
 for(Attachment a:trigger.old){
   aId.add(a.Id);    
 }

 list<Attachment>alist=[select Id, Name,body,ParentId from Attachment  where Id in: aId];
 list<opportunity>crlist =[select Id,OwnerId,owner.name from opportunity where Id =: alist[0].ParentId];
 String parentObj = alist[0].parentId;
 if(parentObj.startsWith('006')) 

    {

      list<User> ulist = [select Id, email from User where Id =:crlist[0].OwnerId];
      String emailId = ulist[0].email;
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

                efa.setFileName(alist[0].Name);
                efa.setBody(alist[0].body);

                       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                       String[] toAddresses = new String[] {emailId,'email@gmail.com'};
                       mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
                       mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);             
                       mail.setSubject('Attachment is deleted');
                       mail.setBccSender(false);
                       mail.setUseSignature(false);
                       mail.setHtmlBody('Hello'+'&nbsp;'+crlist[0].owner.name+','+'<br></br>'+'&nbsp;'+'&nbsp;'+'&nbsp;'+'&nbsp;'+'A file has been deleted'+'&nbsp;'+'<b>'+crlist[0].Name+'</b>'+'&nbsp;'+'in salesforce,'+'&nbsp;'+'please check the attachment here or to view in salesforce'+'&nbsp;'+'<ahref=https://na27.salesforce.com/'+crlist[0].Id+'>click here</a>'+'<br></br>'+'Thank'+'&nbsp;'+'You');
                       Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{mail});
    }

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Much nicer if you would give the forum a start at where the issue is just in case it is not apparent. is it Index 0 does not exist at `String parentObj = alist[0].parentId;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an after delete the record is not visible without using ALL ROWS so the query below:

```
list<Attachment>alist=[select Id, Name,body,ParentId from Attachment  where Id in: aId];
```

will not return any results and thus

```
String parentObj = alist[0].parentId;
```

Will give you index out of bounds

**Change** to a before delete trigger

Comment: Thank you, before delete solved the issue. Do you know what needs to be modified so that i can know which user deleted the file? apparently when file is deleted last modified doesn't gets updated so it is difficult to know who deleted it

Comment: use `userInfo.getUserID()`

Comment: Please mark as accepted answer so others searching for a similar problem can find this question and know it has an answer

Comment: Sorry could you please explain where exactly i have to use that in my trigger?

Comment: @Admin_BA - Where ever it is you want to capture the ID of the user doing the delete

Comment: I have used it in email message ulist[0].Name but it's pulling up the owner name not the person who deleted it

Comment: ulist[0].Name is NOT userInfo.getUserID(); A quick google search will tell you all you need to know about the userInfo methods

Comment: could you please correct my test class? it's failing                                           isTest
private class DeleteAttachment_Test {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
      
        set<Id> aId = new set<id>();
        Order_Management__c om = new Order_Management__c();
        insert om;
 
        Attachment attach=new Attachment();     
        attach.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
        Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        attach.body=bodyBlob;
        attach.parentId=om.id;
        insert attach;    
        delete attach;

            
    }
  }

Comment: Please start a new question

Comment: here is the new question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96025/test-class-for-delete-attachment