# Test class for delete attachment

Tags: apex

How to write test class for trigger where it sends email when an attachment is deleted from opportunity? below is my test class but it fails

```
@isTest
private class DeleteAttachment_Test {

static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

    set<Id> aId = new set<id>();
    Opportunity om = new Opportunity();
    insert om;

    Attachment attach=new Attachment();     
    attach.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
    Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
    attach.body=bodyBlob;
    attach.parentId=om.id;
    insert attach;    
    delete attach;


}
```

}

Comment: 1) How do you know it fails? Where are the system.asserts? (2) A bit more specificity here would be helpful -- SFSE community is good but can't read your mind let alone understand the code of the underlying trigger/classes that isn't presented above. Please update (edit link) the post

Comment: this test class as crop said will only  **execute** lines of code and either **exit** or **throw an error**. It will never pass or fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working unit test class. It's hard to unit test your trigger without looking into the trigger code.

```
@isTest
private class DeleteAttachment_Test {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

        Account acct = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert acct;

        Opportunity om = new Opportunity(Name = 'Name', AccountId = acct.Id, StageName = 'Stage', CloseDate = System.today());
        insert om;

        System.assertEquals(om.name, 'Name');

        Attachment attach = new Attachment();     
        attach.Name = 'Unit Test Attachment';
        Blob bodyBlob = Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        attach.body = bodyBlob;
        attach.parentId = om.id;
        insert attach;  

        List att1 = [select id, name from Attachment where parent.id =: om.id];
        System.assertEquals(1, att1.size());

        delete attach;

        List att2 = [select id, name from Attachment where parent.id =: om.id];
        System.assertEquals(0, att2.size());    


    }
}
```

Comment: asserts for the sake of asserting is no better. you are simply asserting that the attachment was inserted or deleted. if they were not an error would have been thrown....like you said though, hard to test what u do not know....

Comment: Agree. Very little information on the question. This is just a start.

Comment: The above test class works, also i had to change my email deliverability access to all ..thanks guys